Slack API list styling using PHP
I'm trying to send notification messages from my Laravel project's PHP controller to a slack channel. I am able to get it to send with a simple string, like so:
                    Http::post(
                        config('slack_webhook'),
                        [
                            "type" => "rich_text",
                            "text" => "• User: $user_name
                            \n • Email: $user_email
                            \n etc
                            "
                        ]
                    );

However I've been trying to use Slack's documentation to send formatted messages and I can't get it to work. Specifically, I want to use Slack's actual "list" styling as opposed to duping it using unicode characters and new lines like I did above. So, something like this from the docs:
{
    "type": "rich_text",
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text_list",
            "style": "bullet",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_section",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Fill out your W-2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_section",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Enroll in "
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "link",
                            "text": "benefits",
                            "url": "https://salesforcebenefits.com"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_section",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Fill out your Slack profile, including:"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},


So I've tried to format it for PHP but I think I'm doing something wrong.
                    $data =
                        [
                            'type' => "rich_text_list",
                            'text' => "Report1",
                            'elements' => [
                                'type' => 'rich_text_section',
                                'elements' =>
                                    [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'text' => 'test section 1'
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'text' => 'test section 1'
                                    ],

                            ]
                        ];

I also tried
                    $data =
                        [
                            'type' => "rich_text_list",
                            'text' => "Report1",
                            'elements' => [
                                'type' => 'rich_text_section',
                                'elements' =>
                                 [
                                    [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'text' => 'test section 1'
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'type' => 'text',
                                        'text' => 'test section 1'
                                    ],
                                 ]
                            ]
                        ];

I tried the above, and I've also tried creating a json object and using json_decode, and every time I get the following error:
local.ERROR: ErrorException: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

How can I use Slack API formatting in PHP?

Can you add the piece of code, that is sending the actual message payload?

@Tschitsch it's the first snippet I included in the post, it's that Http::post() call

@Tschitsch that config(slack_webhook) references the slack webhook URL in my env file if that helps

but there is no snippet where I can see how $data is processed, there is no indication for a foreach processing. You only posted the "working" snippet.
sitenote: The last two snippets are actually the same, so I have the feeling, that there is something missing. There is no

The example from the docs starts with a "type": "rich_text" element, which you appear to have left out completely.
